Performance vs Balanced power profiles for plugged-in laptop
My laptop's running 22.04 and the power mode feature has "Performance", "Balanced" and "Power Saver". When I'm plugged in, it automatically selects "Balanced".
When plugged in, is there a difference between "Performance" and "Balanced"? Does the latter cause the machine to run more slowly?
